# How to check if android application has permission to use cellular internet?

Tags: android, networking

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve information about mobile data permissions that user can set for any application.
According to this [article](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/data-saver) i can use ConnectivityManager.getRestrictBackgroundStatus(), but it's all about background data, whereas i need information about full restriction.

UPDATE: added screenshot to clarify option than i meant.
[mobile data settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kenVo.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean checkPermission()
{
    String permission = android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET;
    int result = getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;            
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While your code may be helpful, you need to clearly explain how it answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's not what i'm looking for. Your code checks global permission for any network type.

Comment: You wanna check for Cellular Network only or check active internet connection?

Comment: For cellular network only, as described in my question.